# mongodb aggregate dont match own id

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Two Collections:

```
A {_id: ObjectId("5374f3e20ac993835f0001c0"), idsOfB: [...]}
B {_id: ObjectId("5374f3e20ac993835f000aaa"), a: ObjectId("5374f3e20ac993835f0001c0")}
```

All I want is to join this two collections. It should give me all B entries that are not listed in the array of A.

```
db.getCollection('B').aggregate([
  {$match: {a: ObjectId("5374f3e20ac993835f0001c0")}},
  {
    $lookup:{
      from: "A",
      localField: 'a',
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "_a"
    }
  },
  {$unwind: '$_a'},
  {$match:{'_a.idsOfB':{$nin: ['$_id']}}
 }
])
```

This query does not work. Its delivering every time, no mater if the id of B is listed in A.idsOfB or not. So i am sure its taking '$_id' as string and not resolving it to own id. The $ sign seems not to work there.

But if I change match to that...

```
  {$match:{'_a.idsOfB':{$nin: [ObjectId("5374f3e20ac993835f0001c0")]}}
```

... it works fine.

But I need to exclude them automaticaly. I don't want to query all allready listed Ids of B in A like in the second match tho there are many.

What am I doing wrong in the first match version?

---

**More easy verion without lookup:**

```
  tmpStuff
  {
      "_id" : ObjectId("56a88fa0894c9c780f79f30f"),
      "listOfStuff" : [ 
          "stuffA"
      ],
      "stuffType" : "stuffA"
  }
```

This does not work, no mater what I write in the $in arguments:

```
  db.getCollection('tmpStuff').aggregate([
    {$match: {'stuffType': {$in: ['$listOfStuff']}}}
  ])
```

This works fine, but i have to have the list of all possible $in arguments wich are many:

```
  db.getCollection('tmpStuff').aggregate([
    {$match: {'stuffType': {$in: ['stuffA']}}}
  ])
```

Is there a way to reference there to own property listOfStuff within $in?

Comment: Is 'IDOFA' in your working $match a String literal or a defined value/variable?

Comment: can you edit the question defining how the aggregation does not work? In my installation, for instance the $lookup stage is simply missing

Comment: changed, i hope its beter now. $lookup is an outer left join in mongodb >= 3.2.

Comment: ok, i think my problem is, that i dont understand how to use $nin / $in right to point to own property.